# An implementation of Stack in C++ using doubly LL fails with an exception “EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5df48ff8)”

Tags: c++

Goal:
I've implemented a stack using a doubly linked list. I'm using a doubly linked list because the input size is 1 billion and using any other data structure will not render an optimal solution.

Problem:
I have two objects declared in the class MyStack() called root and tail. I want to initialize the values of these two objects to NULL initially. Later, when I call the push() method for the first time, it'll override the values of objects root and tail. 
In my case, the code fails with an exception, “EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5df48ff8) because the value of root is not NULL. I'm not sure where I should be initializing the values so that root and tail don't get overridden until push() is called.

The following is the .h file:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_MYSTACK_H
#define UNTITLED_MYSTACK_H


class MyStack {

    void* data;
    MyStack* next;
    MyStack* prev;
    MyStack* root;
    MyStack* tail;

public:

    MyStack();

    MyStack(void *data);

    MyStack * newNode();

    void *newNode(void* data);

    bool isEmpty(MyStack *root);

    void push(void *data);

    void *pop();

    int size();

    virtual ~MyStack();

};


#endif //UNTITLED_MYSTACK_H
```

The following is the .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "MyStack.h"

using namespace std;

MyStack::MyStack() : root(NULL), tail (NULL) {} // <-- ERROR here -->

MyStack::MyStack(void *data) : data(data) {} // <-- ERROR here -->

MyStack * MyStack::newNode()
{
    MyStack* stackNode;
    stackNode = new MyStack();
    stackNode->data = NULL;
    stackNode->next = NULL;
    stackNode->prev = NULL;
    return stackNode;
}

void* MyStack::newNode(void* data)
{
    MyStack* stackNode;
    stackNode = new MyStack(data);
    stackNode->data = data;
    stackNode->next = NULL;
    stackNode->prev = NULL;
    return stackNode;
}

bool MyStack::isEmpty(MyStack *root) {
    return (root == NULL);
}

void MyStack::push(void *val) {
    if (isEmpty(root)) {

        root->data = newNode(val);
        tail->data = newNode(val);
        tail->next = newNode();
        tail = tail->next;
        root->next = tail;
        tail->prev = root;
        cout << " Element pushed to stack" << tail->data << endl;
    }
    else {
        tail->data = val;
        tail->next = newNode();
        tail->next->prev = tail;
        tail = tail->next;
        cout << " Element pushed to stack" << tail->data << endl;
    }
}


void *MyStack::pop() {
    if (isEmpty(tail)) {
        cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    MyStack* evictedN = new MyStack();
    evictedN = tail;
    tail = tail->prev;
    tail->next = newNode();
    tail = tail->next;
    return evictedN->data;
}


int MyStack::size() {
    if(isEmpty(root)) {
        cout << "Size is empty" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 1;
    while (tail->prev != NULL) {
        count += 1;
        tail = tail->prev;
    }
    return count;
}


MyStack::~MyStack() {

}
//here is my main method

int main() {
    MyStack s;
    elem_t* elem;
    elem->value = 10;
    elem->other = 10 >> 1;
    s.push(elem);
    cout << elem->value << endl;
    cout << elem->other << endl;
    cout << s.pop() << endl;
    cout << s.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag irrelevant languages.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Removed C from the list.

Comment: Your problems might start here in main: `elem_t* elem; elem->value = 10;`. The pointer isn't pointing anywhere, so where does the `10` go?

Comment: @BoPersson : Oh no.. I forgot to paste the struct declaration for elem_t. I'm editing my code now. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: @Akshaya Nice that you'll update that, but it doesn't make what Bo said any less true. The sequence is a blatant invoke of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You should create the `root` node before you try to access it and store data in it. In your `push` method you are checking if there is no root (`if (isEmpty`), but then you try to access the pointer which you know to be null. That would be a good spot to actually create the root node. Then, after you create it, you can store data in it. Same thing with `tail`.

Comment: Finally, I question "I'm using a doubly linked list because the input size is 1 billion" - if the need really is a *only* a **stack**, it doesn't matter how many elements you're putting in to it. It's a LIFO; you don't need a double-linked list. A forward chain is all that is required and a single member pointer will do that.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I would further the question and ask, if this is not a homework assignment, why are you trying to roll your own stack. There is a [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) and if you don't like the performance of the default collection, you can use your own or another of the standard containers that satisfy the underlying requirements (see docs). In general, there is no reason to be using raw pointers in production code. At the very least you should be using some form of smart pointer (shared, unique, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not distinguishing between the stack and the nodes that the stack contains. MyStack::newNode() is returning a completely new stack, not a new node. According to this code:

```
void MyStack::push(void *val) {
  if (isEmpty(root)) {

    root->data = newNode(val);
    tail->data = newNode(val);
    tail->next = newNode();
    tail = tail->next;
    root->next = tail;
    tail->prev = root;
    cout << " Element pushed to stack" << tail->data << endl;
  }
  else {
    tail->data = val;
    tail->next = newNode();
    tail->next->prev = tail;
    tail = tail->next;
    cout << " Element pushed to stack" << tail->data << endl;
  }
}
```

in the case where the root is NULL, isEmpty(root) returns true, so we go ahead and dereference it anyway by accessing root->data. This is undefined behavior.

You need to distinguish between a node and a stack and rewrite the code with that distinction in mind. elem_t could be the node type, or you could define a new class.

Answer (score 0):

here is the MyStack_class.h file:

```
#ifndef MYSTACK_CLASS_H
#define MYSTACK_CLASS_H

class elem_t {
    public:
        int value;
        int other;
        elem_t() {};
        elem_t(int value, int other) : value(value), other(other) {}
        ~elem_t() {};
};

class MyStack {
        private:
                void* data;
                MyStack* next;
                MyStack* prev;
        public:
                MyStack () {}
                MyStack(void* val) : data(val), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
                ~MyStack() {}
                MyStack* newNode();
                MyStack* newNode(void*);
                void push(void*);
                void* pop();
                int size();
};

#endif
```

~

The following is the MyStack_class.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyStack_class.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int count = 0;
MyStack* root = new MyStack();
MyStack* tail = new MyStack();;

MyStack* MyStack::newNode()
{
    MyStack* stackNode;
    stackNode = new MyStack();
    stackNode->data = NULL;
    stackNode->next = NULL;
    stackNode->prev = NULL;
    return stackNode;
}

MyStack* MyStack::newNode(void* data)
{
    MyStack* stackNode;
    stackNode = new MyStack(data);
    stackNode->data = data;
    stackNode->next = NULL;
    stackNode->prev = NULL;
    return stackNode;
}

void MyStack::push (void* val)
{
    if (count == 0) {
        root = newNode(val);
        tail = newNode(val);
        tail->next = newNode();
        tail = tail->next;
        root->next = tail;
        tail->prev = root;
        count++;
        cout << "Element: " << count <<  " pushed to Stack" << endl;
    }
    else {
        tail->data = val;
        tail->next = newNode();
        tail->next->prev = tail;
        tail = tail->next;
        count++;
        cout << " Element " << count << " pushed to stack" << endl;
    }
}

void*  MyStack::pop()
{
    if (count == 0) {
        cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    MyStack* evictedN = new MyStack();
    tail = tail->prev;
    evictedN = tail;
    tail->next = tail->next->prev = NULL;
    count--;
    return evictedN->data;
}

int MyStack::size() {
        int cnt = 0;
        while(root->next != NULL) {
                cnt++;
                root = root->next;
        }
        return cnt;
}
```

The MyStack_class library is used in the following program which can be called
main.cpp or anything that you'd like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "MyStack_class.h"

#define NELEM 1000

using namespace std;

void
example() {
 MyStack* s = new MyStack;
        for (int i = 0; i < NELEM; i++) {
                elem_t* elem = new elem_t(i , i >> 1);
                if (elem == NULL) {
                        exit(1);
                }
                s->push(elem);
                cout << "the pushed element's value and other respectively : " <<  elem->value << " " << elem->other << endl;
        }
        cout << "Stack size : " << s->size() << endl;
        for (int i = (NELEM-1); i > 0; i--) {
                elem_t* elem = static_cast<struct elem_t*>(s->pop());
                if (elem->value != i) {
                        cout << "Error: i is " << i << "and elem-value is " << elem->value << endl;
                }
                cout << "The popped element's value and other respectively: " << elem->value << " " << elem->other << endl;
                delete elem;
        }
        delete s;
}

int
main()
{
    example();
        return 0;
}
```

Here's how my Makefile looks:

```
MyStack_class: MyStack_class.o main.o
    g++ MyStack_class.o main.o -o MyStack_class

MyStack_class.o: MyStack_class.cpp main.cpp
    g++ -c -std=c++0x MyStack_class.cpp main.cpp

clean:
    rm MyStack_class.o main.o MyStack_class
```